# Is it grammatical to say "You're already away."?

Tags: adverbs, collocation, lyrics

I wrote a song including the following lyrics:

> When I take the time it takes to get near
>
> You're probably already away...

And I don't want to change the rhythm of it.
Now my bandmates tell me, I have to add "far" or "gone" before the word "away" i.e.  *far way* and *gone away* to turn it into proper English.
Are they right?

Comment: How does one do any research for this type of question? Do users just vote to close questions they dislike?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It sounds rather unusual, and you'd be unlikely to hear it in natural speech; but since you're a songwriter writing a song, you have quite a lot of poetic licence to play with, and in song lyrics it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the following sentence is perfectly grammatical:

- You're already away.

Prepositions such as *away*, unlike adverbs, are perfectly acceptable as Locative Complements of the verb *BE*.

Consider the simpler sentence:

- They are away at the moment.

which is uncontroversially grammatical.